# Postgresql: find multiple records from comma separated column

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL with Laravel 8.

In a Postgres table, I have one comma separated `character varying` column

[image]

I need those records from this table where value of this comma separated column is 43 OR 56 OR 252.

Comment: That is a really bad design decision. Do you have a chance to fix the broken data model before proceeding?

Comment: No, I can't change DB design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing comma separated values in a single column is a huge mistake to begin with. But if you can't change the data model, you can achieve what you want by converting the value into an array, then use the array [overlaps operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) `&&` with the values you want to test for:

```
select *
from the_table
where string_to_array(bad_column, ',')::int[] && array[43, 56, 252];
```